# how to retrieve image from datagridview to picturebox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
  Private Sub dg1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellDoubleClick
        On Error Resume Next
        tVN.Text = dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
        tNme.Text = dg1.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value
        tCN.Text = dg1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
        tAdd.Text = dg1.Item(3, e.RowIndex).Value
        tVT.Text = dg1.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value
        tTI.Text = dg1.Item(5, e.RowIndex).Value
        tTO.Text = dg1.Item(6, e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim img As Byte
        img = dg1.Item(7, e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)
        pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        txtPIC.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Value
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add a Try..Catch block instead of On Error... so that you can have an idea if there was an error.

Comment: I have to disagree with @F0r3v3r-A-N00b.  There's really no good reason to have an exception handler there because there's no good reason for an exception to be thrown.  You should pretty much NEVER use `On Error Resume Next` in VB.NET but you should only use `Try...Catch` if there's a good reason for an exception to be thrown.  Just run that code in the debugger and your app will crash and the debugger will tell you why and you can then fix your code accordingly. My guess would be that you have a NULL in that column for that row but the error message for the exception will tell you for sure.

Comment: By the way, you should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties immediately and fix all the casting and conversion errors that result.  You should also turn it `On` in the IDE options so that it will be `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: It's never a bad idea to use a try..catch block. In this case, Image.Fromstream will result in an exception if the stream does not have a valid image format or it is null. What if his data source contains a lot of nulls? He'll be dealing with system crash every time.